# conditional replace in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

df:

```
A   B                       C
121 The price is $4M        USA
323 The price is $2.2M      USA
454 The price is $62K       Japan
654 The price is $91M(-21%) Japan
877 The price is $432M(91%) USA
```

I am trying to replace the column B based on the value in column C.

Expected dataframe:

df:

```
A   B                       C
121 The price is $4M        USA
323 The price is $2.2M      USA
454 The price is Y62K       Japan
654 The price is Y91M(-21%) Japan
877 The price is $432M(91%) USA
```

How can i do that?

I have tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
df[(df['C']=='Japan')]['B'].replace(r'\$', "Y")

df[(df['C']=='Japan')]['B'].replace({'$':'Y'}, regex=True)
```

Comment: Why did UK change to Japan where A == 654?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It will either be USA or Japan, nothing else

Comment: You are missing `str`: `df[(df['C']=='Japan')]['B'].str.replace(r'\$', "Y")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mask`:

```
df["B"] = df["B"].mask(df["C"].eq("Japan"), df["B"].str.replace("$", "Y"))

print (df)

     A                        B      C
0  121         The price is $4M    USA
1  323       The price is $2.2M    USA
2  454        The price is Y62K  Japan
3  654  The price is Y91M(-21%)  Japan
4  877  The price is $432M(91%)    USA
```

Answer (score 1):

Use assign function to do what you are doing right now:

```
df = df.assign(
    B = lambda x: x.apply(lambda s: x['B'].replace('$', "Y") if x['C'] =='Japan')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way.

```
df.loc[df['C'] == 'Japan','B'] = df['B'].str.replace('$','Y')
```